# How get ID and value in JComboBox within JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

[`JFrame` in my Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqsCl.png)
[image]

How to get value "item" and "ID" from `JComboBox` in `JTable` by specific row the table?

[Code inside `JComboBox`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTqVE.png)

```
public class ProductItem {
    private int id;
    private String Name;

    public ProductItem() {
    }

    public ProductItem(int id, String Name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoadItem {
    static ResultSet rs = null;
    public static DefaultComboBoxModel LoadProduct(){
        DefaultComboBoxModel ProDuctmodel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        try {
            rs = BarungCls.BarungSelect("select ID, Name from test_data ");
            while(rs.next()){
                ProDuctmodel.addElement(new ProductItem(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)),rs.getString(2)));
            }
            return ProDuctmodel;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Add combo box to table at row 1.

[Add `JCombobox` into `JTable`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncLvG.png)

[image]

Comment: Without having a look at your code instead of a screenshot of some application that could be realized in a lot of different ways I am afraid that we can't realistically help you out here.

Comment: OK i editing my post for my code 

please wait and so sorry i'm new in stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox in the table is the table's editor component. Unless you want to customize the editor, you do not need to get the item of the combo box (the JTable framework will handle the editing for you). Instead, query the table's model for the values you need. Use `JTable.getModel()` to retrieve the table's model and use the model's `getValue(int, int)` method to retrieve the actual values.

Comment: i use ProductItem A = Jtable1.getValue(1,1);
Not work

Comment: @A.Susan `JTable` has no `getValue` method. Do you mean `getValueAt`? And if so, in which way does it not work? Try creating a short, self contained compilable example that lets us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, aside from the fact that you should be using `selectedRow` as the first argument, it is the correct approach. You do realize that column indices start with `0`, right? I.e. `getValueAt(1, 1)` will retrieve the value from the **second** row and **second** column. In your screenshot above, the second column in the table does not display any data. Could it be that your model simply has no values for the second column? What type of model do you use? How do you populate your model?

Comment: Oh Thanks you , i'm so new for netbeans

Comment: Oh Thanks you , i'm so new for netbeans

code for someone 

int num = ((ProductItem)jTable1.getValueAt(1,0)).getId();
or
String S = ((ProductItem)jTable1.getValueAt(1,0)).getName();

Comment: Last a Question How to specific value Item in combobox within Jtable

by use ID from database